# Simple python script is not printing output

Tags: python

This code doesn't print an output:

```
x = 1500000
y = 0

while (x>0):
    x=(x * 1.1) - 20000
    y = y+1
else: 
    print (y)
```

How would one fix this problem?

---

Comment: Add some more `print`s to find out what is going on

Comment: `x` is always greater than 0, because it is always increasing, so the loop never exits. (Actually, after a few seconds `x` ends up as `inf`: infinity.) The `else` clause only executes if the loop exits normally (without a `break` statement). As to fixing it... there's no way to know that without knowing what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I suspect that you meant to start with 150000, not 1500000 - the loop actually terminates after about 15 iterations that way.

Answer (score 1):

See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.  Most of all, learn to use a `print` to trace the problem, or desk-check the program (simulate with paper & pencil).

Look at your very first iteration:

```
x = 1500000
y = 0

while (x>0):
    x=(x * 1.1) - 20000
```

Evaluate this line:

```
x = (1500000 * 1.1) - 20000
x = 1650000 - 20000
x = 1630000
```

x is now *larger* than before.  It will continue to escalate without bound.  You never reach your `while`'s exit condition, so you never reach the `print` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `x>0` it will never be false because your `x` always will increase.

Ex:
* start code:
x = 1500000
y = 0

- first iteration:
  x = 1630000
  y = 1
- second iteration:
  x = 1773000
  y = 2
- 3th iteration:
  x = 1930300
  y = 3

So your code never into in `else`.